# Participant Custom Data not saving

Tags: custom-fields

I have created custom fields for a site. All of them work except those connected to Participants. When data is entered into the backend, data will not save, and no error is issued. 
The fields also won't show up to be added to profiles.

I have upgraded from 4.5.8 to 4.6.2, had no effect. 
Also I rebuilt the database schema and the problem persists. 
There is no custom code. The site is using Drupal 6 on CiviHosting. 
I have tested it on the demo site and on other civicrm installs.

Is there anything else worth trying or worth looking into?

Answer (score 2):

Can you double check and see that the custom group is extending Participants and not Events? The two are different entities, but a fair number of users have made this mistake in the past.

A few other thoughts:

- Can you also elaborate on where it does not work for participants?
- Can you try the same sequence of steps on our demo servers and see if you can reproduce it there

Comment: It is definitely participants.

Comment: i modified my answer and asked for a few more clarification. you can edit your question with the clarifications